# How to turn off the SQLite journal for access from a read-only filesystem?

Tags: c, sqlite, pragma, journal

I want to query a SQLite database which is stored on a read-only file system.
The `PRAGMA` statement should exactly do this:

```
sqlite3_stmt* pVM;
sqlite3* mpDB;

sqlite3_open_v2(szFile, &mpDB, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, 0);   // SQLITE_OK

sqlite3_exec(mpDB, "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;", NULL, 0, 0);

sqlite3_prepare_v2(mpDB, "SELECT samplevalue FROM table;", 1, &pVM, 0); // SQLITE_OK
if (sqlite3_step(pVM) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    // Get value
    printf("Value: %d", sqlite3_column_int(pVM, 0)); // OK but journal is still 
                                                     // created on disk
}

sqlite3_finalize(pVM);  // SQLITE_OK
```

My second gues was that the `PRAGMA`statement could be part of each query statement:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(mpDB, "PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY; SELECT samplevalue FROM table;", 1, &pVM, 0); // SQLITE_OK
if (sqlite3_step(pVM) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    // Get value
    printf("Value: %d", sqlite3_column_int(pVM, 0)); // Value "0" is returned
}
```

This does not work because only the `PRAGMA`part is executed.

How can I execute queries without SQLite trying to create a journal?

Regards,

Comment: What is the name of that created file?

Comment: The filename is ``mydatabase.sqlitedb-journal`` (where ``mydatabase.sqlitedb`` is the database filename).

Comment: The journal is not kept unless you are in TRUNCATE or PERSIST mode, and it is not created unless you are changing the database. Why do you think that the code you've shown *creates* the journal file?

Comment: because it's the only code which I execute.

Comment: `PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;` seems to work for me. Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: Maybe not related to your problem, but in your `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` statement, shouldn't the third parameter (`1`) be either negative or the length of the SQL statement?